# Compress WireClouds JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, django, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Every time I reload the WireCloud workspace it takes like forever to load all the JavaScript files. The network console of my browser indicates that there are about 300 requests to retrieve all needed JavaScript resources. Those resources my only take about 30ms to load each, but the huge amount of requests causes the dashboard to almost take a minute to fully load.

Even the initial WireCloud landing page uses about 250 requests and thus take like forever to load and does not really contain content.

So is there a way to compress those JavaScript files and / or to unify them? The files from the server even contain comments and linebreaks. As far as I know this should not be the case in JavaScript files that are used in production.

Comment: I assume you are talking about a 'local' installation? How does your configuration look like?

Comment: What do you understand as a local installation? The WireCloud applications is installed on one of our regular servers and the wsgi script gets used by an apache. To set up this I followed the instructions described [here](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_guide/#installing-wirecloud-using-pip-recommended)

Comment: it actually has compression implemented - see [here](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/blob/develop/src/settings.py#L64). are you sure you have `DEBUG=False` in your settings? as this likely will disable compression.

Comment: Indeed, `DEBUG=True` was still active. It reduced the requests to about 150 instead of the 300. But it seems that every Widget and Operator of WireCloud queries either `https://wirecloud.example.com/static/js/WirecloudAPI/WirecloudOperatorAPI.js` or `https://wirecloud.example.com/static/js/WirecloudAPI/WirecloudAPIBootstrap.js?v=1b1ae443eeec423c4f3083d2096502f864ea01fa` and those files are not compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WireCloud uses `django-compressor` for unify JavaScript and CSS files and should be enabled if `DEBUG` is `False` in your `settings.py` file.

I've tested in the FIWARE Lab's Mashup portal with a dashboard composed of 4 widgets and 4 operators, this lead to ~100 request (javascript files, initial ajax request, css files, ...). But take into account that almost all of those request should come from cache (they are no real requests):

[image: Request from cache]

Check your Apache configuration if you don't see this behaviour. Others requests should be returning a `304` error code, so they are real requests but of a ridiculous size if the response has not changed:

[image]

Anyway, we're working on reducing the required requests and we're open to any suggestion (would be great if you [open a ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/new) with the suggestion of compressing `WirecloudAPI` files for widgets and operators).

Comment: Yeah, behaviour is as you described. I will open a ticket.